# static files with express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I want to serve `index.html` and `/media` subdirectory as static files. The index file should be served both at `/index.html` and `/` URLs.

I have

```
web_server.use("/media", express.static(__dirname + '/media'));
web_server.use("/", express.static(__dirname));
```

but the second line apparently serves the entire `__dirname`, including all files in it (not just `index.html` and `media`), which I don't want.

I also tried

```
web_server.use("/", express.static(__dirname + '/index.html'));
```

but accessing the base URL `/` then leads to a request to `web_server/index.html/index.html` (double `index.html` component), which of course fails.

Any ideas?

---

By the way, I could find absolutely no documentation in Express on this topic (`static()` + its params)... frustrating. A doc link is also welcome.

Comment: As of express 4.x, `express.static()` is handled by `serve-static` package middleware.  you can find its docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static or https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static.

Comment: can someone please explain what "server as static files" means?

Comment: @iLiveInAPineappleUnderTheSea In a dynamic web application, such as when using Express, the page content is created - or generated - by the application. On the other hand, static files are served (mostly) unmodified from a static directory hierarchy. For example, while the pages may change, the image files, CSS files, and Javascript files do not.

Comment: check below link http://only4ututorials.blogspot.com/2017/05/how-to-serve-static-file-in-express-js.html

Comment: Here I made a video for similar purpose. It uses express and serve-index to make complete file sharing solution over the lan. https://youtu.be/4S6doMsaT78

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`express.static()` expects the first parameter to be a *path* of a directory, not a filename.  I would suggest creating another subdirectory to contain your `index.html` and use that.

Serving static files in Express [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), or [more detailed `serve-static` documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html), including the [default behavior of serving `index.html`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html#index):

> By default this module will send “index.html” files in response to a request on a directory. To disable this set false or to supply a new index pass a string or an array in preferred order.

Comment: And just for information, it will serve up index.html by default in that other directory

Comment: If there is only ONE parameter - then `express.static` expects that one parameter to be path....

Comment: Side question, how do you for instance make "/" render "/welcome.html" from the public folder? Right now I use "res.sendFile" and load the file from the server (so not using the fact that it's a public file), but maybe a rewrite/redirect could be more appropriate?

Answer (score 226):

If you have this setup

```
/app
   /public/index.html
   /media
```

Then this should get what you wanted

```
var express = require('express');
//var server = express.createServer();
// express.createServer()  is deprecated. 
var server = express(); // better instead
server.configure(function(){
  server.use('/media', express.static(__dirname + '/media'));
  server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

server.listen(3000);
```

The trick is leaving this line as last fallback

```
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

As for documentation, since Express uses connect middleware, I found it easier to just look at the connect source code directly.

For example this line shows that index.html is supported
https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.3.3/lib/middleware/static.js#L140

Comment: `Application.configure()` was documented as legacy in 3.x and removed in 4.x.  See ChrisCantrell's answer for an updated example.

Comment: what is the `__dirname`? Whats its value?

Comment: outdated for latest express.

Answer (score 158):

In the newest version of express the "createServer" is deprecated. This example works for me:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

//app.use(express.static(__dirname)); // Current directory is root
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); //  "public" off of current is root

app.listen(80);
console.log('Listening on port 80');
```

Comment: __dirname is keyword?

Comment: It is a global in your nodejs module. http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Comment: __dirname isn't actually a global but rather local to each module.

Comment: this is the  equivalent in python of `__file__` which you use with `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

Comment: @ChrisCantrell How I can add to static folder if I have file in `public/teams/logo.png` ?

Answer (score 59):

`res.sendFile` & `express.static` both will work for this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var public = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

// viewed at http://localhost:8080
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(public, 'index.html'));
});

app.use('/', express.static(public));

app.listen(8080);
```

Where `public` is the folder in which the client side code is

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js/43312722?noredirect=1#comment87150340_43312722) by [@ATOzTOA](https://stackoverflow.com/u/1729773) and [clarified by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js/43312722?noredirect=1#comment87239542_43312722) [@Vozzie](https://stackoverflow.com/u/2178666/), `path.join` takes the paths to join as arguments, the `+` passes a single argument to path.

Comment: `path.join` takes the paths to join as arguments, the `+` passes a single argument to path.

Comment: @ATOzTOA can you explain more please

Comment: What @ATOzTOA is saying is you should change `path.join(public + 'index.html')` into `path.join(public, 'index.html')` And while at it, change `__dirname + "/public/"` into `path.join(__dirname, 'public')`

Comment: This helped me in combining a static site with an API all in one

Answer (score 10):

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');

const app = new express();
app.use(express.static('/media'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'media/page/', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('App listening on port 4000')
})
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have a complicated folder structure, such as

```
- application
     - assets
         - images
             - profile.jpg
     - web
     - server
        - index.js
```

If you want to serve `assets/images` from `index.js`

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'assets', 'images')))
```

To view from your browser

```
http://localhost:4000/images/profile.jpg
```

If you need more clarification comment, I'll elaborate.

Comment: my assets folder contain css , js , images . How can I get them by  using this method . note : I have also same folder structure . @SaahityanVigneswaran

Answer (score 5):

use below inside your app.js

```
app.use(express.static('folderName'));
```

(folderName is folder which has files) - remember these assets are accessed direct through server path (i.e. http://localhost:3000/abc.png  (where as abc.png is inside folderName folder)

Answer (score 3):

> npm install serve-index

```
var express    = require('express')
var serveIndex = require('serve-index')
var path = require('path')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')
var app = express()
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
/**for files */
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
/**for directory */
app.use('/', express.static('public'), serveIndex('public', {'icons': true}))

// Listen
app.listen(port,  function () {
  console.log('listening on port:',+ port );
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add something that is on the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), and it's sometimes misread in tutorials or others.

```
app.use(mountpoint, middleware)
```

**mountpoint** is a virtual path, it is not in the filesystem (even if it actually exists). The mountpoint for the middleware is the `app.js` folder.

Now

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public')`
```

will send files with path `/static/hell/meow/a.js` to `/public/hell/meow/a.js`

Answer (score 0):

This is the error in my case when I provide links to HTML files.

**before:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/style.css">
```

**After:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

I just removed the static directory path from the link and the error is gone. This solves my error one thing more don't forget to put this line where you are creating the server.

```
var path = require('path');
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Answer (score -1):

> ### You can make your own function to do it like this:
>
> ---
>
> ```
> const static = (root = "") => app.get(/./, (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + root + req.url));
> ```

> ### You can also do it with express like this:
>
> ---
>
> ```
> app.use('/', express.static(public));
> ```

Answer (score -3):

You can achieve this by just passing the second parameter express.static() method to specify index files in the folder

```
const express = require('express');
const app = new express();
app.use(express.static('/media'), { index: 'whatever.html' })
```