# Static files served by node.js on heroku - is it a good idea?

Tags: node.js, seo, single-page-application, static-files

I have Backbone powered single page app. App consists of couple of files:

```
index.html
javascripts/app.js
javascripts/vendor.js
stylesheets/app.css
images/ -> image assets
```

I want to add `prerender.io` service to my app to make it SEO-friendly. The easiest way of doing this for me is to use `express.js` hosted on `heroku`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', 'YOUR_TOKEN'));
// ...
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

But maybe `express` or actually `node` are not best for serving static files?
Maybe `heroku` isn't best for serving static files?
What will be best solution? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See this StackOverflow question for serving static files through expressjs: [static files with express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js)

You should be able to use Heroku's free dyno to handle a good bit of traffic since you're only serving static files.

I would suggest putting all of those files/folder in a "public/" directory and using this code:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You better use CDN for serving static files like Amazon S3.

Comment: But I have to "catch" all google-spider request for example and redirect them to prerender.io. So request sequence should be -> `myapp.com => (server) => CDN:index.html` - is it possible? The problem is that I have to "catch" all requests in (server) step to redirect them to `prerender.io` if needed...