# How to serve a Gitbook on Heroku

Tags: heroku, gitbook

I have a [Gitbook](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook) repository and I would like to serve it through [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). How should I setup my application for this purpose? How to tell `Gitbook serve' command to listen to Heroku's port?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Add [gitbook-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitbook-cli) to your project:

```
npm install --save gitbook-cli
```

2- Add a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) to your project:

```
web: ./node_modules/gitbook-cli/bin/gitbook.js serve --port $PORT
```

Comment: This way will chew a lot of memory, your app will crash with the 512MB dyno. Check the logs on Heroku once your app is running, you will notice.

Answer (score 5):

Do not run the `gitbook-cli` directly on Heroku, gitbbok will use a lot of memory and pass the 512MB limit for a free dyno. The best way is to first build your book to a static website and then serve the static content with either *nodejs* with *express* static or with *sinatra*.

Run the following inside your *gitbook* folder.

```
gitbook build
```

A new folder will be created, `_book` and all your html files will be here. You can now create a new app on Heroku and serve your static content.

After you do `gitbook build`, you can serve that directory with [Express](https://expressjs.com/) by creating an `app.js` file like this:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/_book'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Dead-easy. For more information: [Static files served by node.js on heroku - is it a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297072/static-files-served-by-node-js-on-heroku-is-it-a-good-idea)