# express js routing issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wish to call my index.html page while using `sendFile`, but I ran into a problem.
The problem is that it actually shows me the index.html although without any css and js\jquery effects.

server.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var server = app.listen(8000, function () {

var host = server.address().address;
var port = server.address().port;

console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)

});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')

});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js     alskjdf

Comment: You have to define routing that supports your JS and CSS external files, probably using `express.static()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add this line to your code

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // or another directory, it depends on where your static files are located
```

this is middleware to serve files from given directory, [there is very good article about this middleware](http://evanhahn.com/express-dot-static-deep-dive/)