# Javascript file not loading in MEAN stack application

Tags: javascript, html, mean-stack

I am playing around and trying to learn the MEAN stack to create a single page application. I was able to get my back-end routes to work correctly. I've tested it using Postman and get the results I expect, however I cannot get my front-end to talk to the back-end correctly.

I reduced my front-end to very basic html and javascript, but still get a syntax error "Unexpected token <". When I inspect my coreTest.js file in the browser, I see that it's just a copy of my html file, rather than javascript code.

When I run index.html by itself (without server.js) coreTest.js runs just fine. I'm not sure why, when running my server.js file, my coreTest.js file doesn't work properly.

### server.js

```
// Setup

var express = require('express');
var app = express();            // create app w/ express

var mongoose = require('mongoose');             // used for MongoDB connection
var morgan = require('morgan');             // log requests to the console
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');            // pull information from HTML POST
var methodOverride = require('method-override');            // simulate DELETE and PUT requests


// Configure

mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/test');       // connect to localhost db "test"

// varify connection
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error: '));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));         // set static files location
app.use(morgan('dev'));         // log every request to console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));        // parse application/x-www-form-url
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());

// define db model
var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', {
    text: String
});


var router = express.Router();

router.route("/todos")

    .get(function(req, res) {
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(todos);
        });
    })

    .post(function(req, res) {
        var todo = new Todo();
        todo.text = req.body.text;

        todo.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({mes: "Todo item created"});
        })
    });

router.route("/todos/:todo_id")

    .delete(function(req, res) {
        Todo.remove( {
            _id: req.params.todo_id
        }, function(err, todo) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({mes: "Successfully deleted"});
        });
    });

// route to application
router.route("*")
    .get(function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
    });

// Register our routes
app.use('/api', router);

// Listen, start node app
app.listen(8080);
console.log("app listening on port 8080");
```

### coreTest.js

```
alert("ping");
```

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Starter MEAN Single Page Application</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="coreTest.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    I did it!! Wooo!!

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is between

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and

```
// route to application
router.route("*")
.get(function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});
```

When you're running the server, your client-side code is trying to load "coreTest.js", which is matched by the last rule ; and so the server returns the content of index.html.

I'm not sure what you mean about "runing index.html by itself" ; if you mean "visiting file://..../public/index.html", it works because the browser will try to load coreTest.js from your *file system*.

Try using the "static" plugin only to serve files from "public", and use this prefix in the client side code :

```
app.use("/public", express.static(...))
```

and in the client

```
<script type=".." src="public/coreTest.js"></script>
```

Getting the path rights will depend on what's on your disk.

This might help, too : [static files with express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue using what phtrivier recommended.

Instead of serving my files from "public" I chose to serve them from "api" because I already set my router to take requests from that path as well.

```
app.use("/api", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I didn't need to change my reference to coreTest.js in the html because my files were organized with coreTest already in the root directory like this:

```
public
   -index.html
   -coreTest.js
```