# Loading HTML files in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to load HTML files in nodejs. In public folder, I have two html files test.html and index.html. I would like to use nodejs to showcase the pages, but its working for index.html and for the case of test, it shows an error saying that res.sendFile is not a function.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

// viewed at http://localhost:8080 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});
// viewed at http://localhost:8080 
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/test.html'));
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: For express 4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js#10440149

Comment: The code works fine when I run it. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I am using an outdated package

Answer (score 0):

For serving static files such as JS, CSS, images, html files, you can use  the **express.static** built-in middleware function in Express. 
[Serving static files in Express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Say if your 'Public' folder has some JS, html files which is required at client side. Then you need do to go like this :-

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var server = app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Well … you *can*, but why doesn't the current approach work?