# Socket.io client library not getting loaded

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am going through the example listed below:

https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

The part where they add a script link to the socket.io is where the problem starts. The client side library is never found.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The app.js code looks like this:

```
var express = require('express')
const app = express()
var http = require('http').Server(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(http)


app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user is connected')
})

app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Server has started")
})
```

I have already installed express and socket.io using npm package manager.

When I run the page I get the following error:

[image]

UPDATE: This works.

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io')

var app = express()
var server = app.listen(4000,function(){
  console.log("listening on port 4000")
})

var io = socket(server)

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user is connected')
})
```

Comment: are you serving static assets with express?

Comment: How you are you loading the web page into your browser.  If you load the web page from `http://localhost:3000/`, then your code should work because the web page comes from your server so the browser will likewise attempt to load `/socket.io/socket.io.js` from the same server.  If you load the web page directly from the file system into the browser, then it will not work because the browser will try to load `/socket.io/socket.io.js` from the file system and it will not find it.

Comment: You need to serve [static files with express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js) ... that also assumes you have the socket.io file in that directory.

Comment: @jakerella - That is not correct.  The socket.io library will automatically server `/socket.io/socket.io.js` from its own directory hierarchy in response to that route request if everything is properly configured.  There is no need for explicit static file serving for `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.  This is a built-in feature of the server-side socket.io code (that it automatically serves the client-side files).

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have the proper server-side socket.io library installed on your server because the code, as you show it, will work when properly installed.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the question with the solution that worked. Thanks for your help!