# How to stop express from incorrectly interpreting path inside of static index.htm file

Tags: node.js, express

I'm testing express and I ran across a problem that I haven't found a good solution for.  My relative paths inside of index.htm are getting confused by a route.

Inside of server.js I include the following basic route.

**server.js**

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.htm'));
});
```

The folder `/public` contains my index.htm file.

The folder `/public/images` contains a single .png file used for testing.

Inside of index.htm I include the following line of code.

**index.htm**

```
<img src="images/testImage.png">
```

On a standard website this simple directory structure works fine.  When index.htm is rendered it looks one directory up to /images to find testImage.png.  However when I call it with an express route it gets confused and can't find the image.

In my browser when I visit `http://localhost:3000/` the route correctly finds index.htm inside of the public folder.  Unfortunately it renders the image link as broken and it gives me this error.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/images/testImage.png 404 (Not Found)
```

I can fix the problem by including this line of code in server.js.  It tells express that calls to /images should actually go to public/images.

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/images')));
```

But going forward that line makes things more confusing and could lead to other problems.

Is there a standard practice to solve this kind of problem?  Thanks so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [static files with express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js) (you should mount your entire `public` folder as static, rather than specifically linking the images folder)

Comment: `app.use(express.static('public'))` to serve static files from the public folder. https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Bear in mind that relative links in HTML are resolved based on the URL, not the location on disk. If your server doesn't actually serve the `images` folder anywhere, your users won't be able to access it.