# how to access images on disk on localhost and access via url on website

Tags: node.js, image, express

I have few question concerning image storage on a website.

For efficiency, I store images on local disk and image path into db. say, image1.png stores on `uploads/img` folder with path(from `req.file.path`) as `uploads/img/image1.png`.

now, how to access this path via url. I have tried to call
`http://localhost:3000/uploads/img/image1.png`
and
`file:///uploads/img/image1.png` but nothing worked.

any help.

Comment: can you post your code.

Comment: Fixed, as suggested in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js .