# Node.js serve html files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, backend

I have a directory structure like this :

```
    server
       code
         app.js
         web
           html
               index.html
           css
               index.css
           scripts
               index.js
```

My app.js code is trying to serve the html file index.html but shows errors 
this is the code :

```
    app.get('/web',function(req,res) 
    {
        res.sendFile('../web/html/index.html');
    })
```

What path to pass to sendFile() and make it work appropriately so that the script file and css are also found by the html file when it runs ?

I'm new to node.js.

Comment: try `res.sendFile('./web/html/index.html')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [static files with express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js)

Comment: @Jhecht i tried your answer but i got the following output :

> TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile

Comment: then try `res.sendFile('./web/html/index.html', { root : __dirname })`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `express.static("")` to serve static files. 
Example:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {});
app.use(express.static("./web"));
```

This will make everything in the web folder public, and the index.html file can be found at `localhost:PORT/html/index.html`
This will also serve your `js` and `css` files correctly

To serve the html separately you will need to use an absolute path:

```
app.get('/web',function(req,res) 
{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './web/html/index.html'));
})
```

remember to include `const path = require(path)`

Comment: quick comment -- based on the directory structure above, it looks like `web/` is in the same folder as `app.js`. unless OP would like to clarify that part via screenshot.