# How does express know this routing?

Tags: node.js, express

I create a simple express server and serve the static files

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('Listening on port 3000')
})
```

When I head to localhost:3000, the index.html in my public directory renders for the route ' / '. I didn't explicitly write the route in my index.js file. How does express know this?

I've tried changing the file name from index.html to random.html and I get an error. CANNOT GET /

Comment: `app.use(express.static('public'));`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `app.use(express.static('public'))` is responsible for this. This will essentially serve all files in the `public` folder you have in the project. If you have an `index.html` in the `public` folder, then that will be served at the `/` endpoint automatically. This is a convention that most websites follow, and is documented in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js).

Here is the relevant documentation on `express.static(...)`: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html