# Angular Universal: do not render some pages

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have developed an Angular Universal project. All pages are rendered using express like this:

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [
            { provide: href, useValue: req.baseUrl },
            { provide: REQUEST, useValue: req },
            { provide: RESPONSE, useValue: res }
        ]});
});
```

But, I have also some personalized URLs, that I don't want to prerender, I just want that express respond simple static index file, which browser will load. I was trying like this:

```
server.get('/personal-information', express.static(indexHtml));
```

But no result. Please help.

Comment: What's the issue your facing, what do you get as response? Is it the regular one instead of `/personal-information` config?

Comment: @PraveenThirumurugan the issue is that these pages are still rendering on server side, but i do not want this

Answer (score 0):

> express.static() expects the first parameter to be a path of a
>   directory, not a filename. I would suggest creating another
>   subdirectory to contain your index.html and use that. [Refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10440149/2501581).

So if you have something like:

```js
  server.get('*.*', express.static('public'));
```

You need to create a folder called `personal-information` inside your public path and put your index.html there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also parse the URL like this in your code.

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const params = req.params[0].split("/");
    if (params[1] && params[1] === "personal-information") {
        res.send(indexHtml);
    }
    else {
        res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [
            { provide: href, useValue: req.baseUrl },
            { provide: REQUEST, useValue: req },
            { provide: RESPONSE, useValue: res }
        ]
    }
});
```

Using this approach, you can separate URL into different parts and compute logic based on your needs. For example, if the API call URL is `https://example.com/personal-information`, then `params[0]` will be `example.com` and `params[1]` will be `personal-information`. This will help you solve the problem you are facing.

Comment: it is just printing word "index" on screen