# How to properly use serve-static?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This question tightly relates to [This issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693118/nodejs-app-cant-find-process-vue-js-and-other-files).

I'm building an nodeJS app. You can see the file architecture in the screenshot below.
[image]

When I try running my index.JS file:

```
const express = require('express')
const server     = new express()
const srcDir  = require('app-root-path');
const port = 3000

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(`${srcDir}/app/views/index.html`)
})


server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

**Issue:** I get a blank page, where the console says that everything supplementary in my "app" folder (APART FROM HTML FILES THEMSELVES!) (components (js files), assets (css), e.t.c.) is unreachable: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.  I know that the origin of the issue might be in establishing serve-static (which I don't understand), although it has always worked perfectly without it.

Can anyone help out? Thanks in advance.

P.S.
Console logs:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [static files with express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell Express where the root directory of your static files is. Usually in the wild - this directory is called `public` and will contain all of your css, js files, which you want to ship to the browser. Do **not** include `views` or any other backend files.

So in your case: create a new directory called `public` and put `assets` and `components` in there.

Then in your Express server:

```
app.use(express.static(`${srcDir}/app/public`));
```

- Docs: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks a lot for the help, @madflow! Everything worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the methods outlined in the [express.js docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

```
const staticDir = './views' // Or wherever it's being served from
server.use(express.static(staticDir));
```

You can also choose a specified path pre-fix to show these files from

```
server.use('/static', express.static(staticDir))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "components" with `express.static("directory")`, like it's explained here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

In your case, add this in your app.

```js
server.use(express.static("app/components"));
```

To access the file `FeaturePage/MainDisplay.js` for example, you have to use this in your html.

```html
<script src="/FeaturePage/MainDisplay.js"></script>
```