# How can I allow a user to download a file from a link in express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, get, mern

I have a function that allows you to create a folder in the directory where the server is located, and upload files there
And I'm trying to access them via a direct link, like this

*http://localhost:5000/attachments/1618413024408--1.jpg*

Because, the file is located here
[image]

But why can't I access it?

```
Cannot GET /attachments/1618413024408--1.jpg
```

Comment: Does this answer help? [static files with express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10434001/996081)

Comment: Just as a precaution, be aware that it is not a good idea to store user uploaded files directly on your server, as they may be rewritten every time you redeploy your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express itself provides an easy to use implementation for this `express.static(root, [options])`.

Simply add this add the right position in your code:

```
app.use('/attachments', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'attachments')))
```

Make sure that `path.join(__dirname, 'attachments')` points to the right directory (with a simple console.log) otherwise just adjust it.

Documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 0):

try to use express function sendFile

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

something like this

```
app.use('/attachments/:filename', (req, res) => {
   const myIms = <path to directory>
   const filePath = myIms + '/attachments/' + req.filename
    res.sendFile(filePath, {
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'
      }
    })
})
```

or  express download function https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download