# How to send multiple files to clients(as source of the) page in node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am working on a `node js` app.

This is the code of the `index.html` file

```
<h1 id="h">hello</h1>
<script src="client.js"></script>
```

I am willing to change the `innerHTML` of that h1 to hai.

This my code in the `client.js` file

```
document.getElemntById("h").innerHTML = "hai";
```

*I don't like using script tags in html*

I have these codes in the server.js file(main file);

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
});
```

But, It is only sending the `index.html`.It is not sending the `client.js`. I also tried inserting multiple parameters.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html",__dirname+"/client.js");
});
```

It is not still working.

What should I do?

### *I am new to programming, node, and StackOverflow.So please forgive me if there Are any problems*

Comment: You need to set up express to send static files.

Comment: Docs are your best friend: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Duplicate: [static files with express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.sendFile` & `express.static` both will work for this

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var public = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

// viewed at http://localhost:8080
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(public, 'index.html'));
});

app.use('/', express.static(public));

app.listen(8080);
```

Where your `public` directory will contain all `*.css`, `*.js` and other files

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/musafiroon-forked-nlp1d?file=/views/style.css     This is the link.

Comment: I have many folders like this.Do I have to write this code for every folder?