# Express Send Files in Folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, directory

I have a server with files like this:

```
- index.js
/client
 -index.html
 -about.html
 -signup.html
 -style.css
```

In index.js I have a express server.

- When the user goes to `/` , it should go to index.html
- When the user goes to `/about.html` it should go to about.html etc
- When the user goes to `/style.css` it should go to style.css etc..

I know you can do it like this..

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html')
})
```

But I want to make it so that it automatically sends the correct file without having to `get` each folder.

I know it has something to do with `app.use` but I am not fully sure how to use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, I never thought it would be this easy-

`app.use('/', express.static('client'))`