# React: import an image from my Node backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

in my backend I am using Multer to save images in my server. They are saved in my images folder:

[image]

With react, I try to recover these images. I have the URL of the image in my props (mediaURL is http://localhost:4200/images/1635506218497.png) and so I do a src={mediaURL} but it does not display the image to me, only the alt attribute.

So I try to hand write the absolute path to the image or the relative path, but I have an error: "Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../../ ../../back-end/images/1635506218497.png which falls outside of the project src / directory. Relative imports outside of src / are not supported. "

Same thing if I try to import the image via a module.

This is my front :
[image]

How do I display my image?

I don't know if it's related but when I type http: // localhost: 4200 / images / 1635506218497.png in my browser, I have a "Cannot GET /images/1635506218497.png" but my backend is running on port 4200.

Comment: Anyone can help ? :/

Comment: The issue is not with React. If you can't request the image directly via the URL, the issue must be with the backend. If your backend was serving the image successfully, your React would work as far as I can tell.

Comment: Are you using the `static` middleware ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Indeed, the problem was in Node, in fact, i wasn't using static middleware. so i put app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
in my app.js and everything works. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Well, i just forgotten to use static middleware in my app.js.

app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));

Now its work