How do I host a Vue/Vite app with Express server on a hosting providor server?
I have a multiplayer game website similar to say chess.com or lichess but for another game. I use Vite with Vue for front end and express for backend, comminucation with socket.io and database in mongodb.
It all works fine on localhost so now I want to try and upload to my hosting providor. I have a virtual private server (VPS) which uses Direct Admin which has access to my folder structure under mywebsite.com folder.
I have a .env file which holds the variable VITE_SERVER_URI=http://localhost:5000 and then I have a .env.production file which similarily holds VITE_SERVER_URI=https://mywebsite.com.
The project structure is I have a root which in turn holds .env, .env.production, src etc. Then src holds my vue components and also the server folder which holds the server.js file which looks like this:
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import authRoutes from './routes/auth.js';
import http from 'http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

// Set up dotenv
dotenv.config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '../../.env') });

// Cors
const allowedOrigins = [
    'http://localhost:5000',
    'http://localhost:5173',
    'https://mywebsite.com',
  ];

// Create app
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({ 
    origin: allowedOrigins,
    credentials: true,
}));

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
    .catch(err => console.error('MongoDB connection error:', err));

// Create HTTP server and socket.io instance
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: allowedOrigins,
        methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE"],
        credentials: true
    }
});

// Set up the routes
app.use('/api', authRoutes);

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

What works

Everything works on localhost:5173, communication with database and socket io works as expected.
I can build my project with npm run build which creates the dist folder. It I put content of that into public_html I can see my front end as expected.

What doesn't work

I have no clue how to get backend to work on both localhost and on VPS server at my host.

What I tried

If I Google or use chatgpt I get different answers and I can't get any of them to work
Upload the server files to the root of my domain folder, outside of public_html. However I get both Cors errors and not found errors in console.
All variations of trying to server my static files from server or other configs. However none works in production, and many of the ways breaks localhost.

Questions

How should I configure my server to work both locally and in production?
How do I upload this to my VPS/domain to make it work on the internet?

Please let me know if you need more code or information.

The problem is that you try to run "dev" server in prod, and you shouldn't. Generally vite part shouldn't be there. Build vue app to dist/ static files on deploy and make sure they are served from the root of the same domain as express server. You don't need cors when you can avoid it, this is the way this can be done. It's unknown whether your web server that uses public_html is configured to do this, or you'll need express static middleware, but anyway

@EstusFlask, I am sorry but I am not entirely sure what you mean. Where do I run dev server in prod? Please explain how I deploy my express server and "talk" to it from front end

What exactly do you do to run the app locally? I assume you did something like npm run dev, which is usual for vite setup. And you shouldn't do this in prod. Instead do npm run build and deploy static files from "dist"

@EstusFlask yes that is exactly what I wrote under "what works", I do npm run build and put content of dist folder into public html. But that is just front end stuff, which displays nicely. However I get errors since I don't have server connection, or host server. How should I deploy the express server parts?

You need to configure web server to do this. The question doesn't contain anything about it. Is it nginx or?

@EstusFlask I think they run apache if that is what you mean

You need to run express on vps and configure web server to bind (this is the term you need to be aware of for your case) mywebsite.com:443 to localhost:5000. Doing this and serving static files from public_html simultaneously may require advanced config, to make it more simple you can serve static files from dist/ with express static middleware instead. Any way, this is totally specific to web server you have and your ability to configure it. I don't use Direct Admin and can't say if it allows this

@EstusFlask I understand you don't know specifics, don't worry. Is it really this hard to deploy a website with a server? I thought there would be more of an easy way, a standard thing.

Totally depends on a server and the way it's configured, including control panel. Even with manual web server config this is a trivial thing that needs 2 min setup once you know what you're doing. You can sort it out yourself by running nginx locally. CP can make this easier or harder.  You need a guide how to set up node.js app for your vps and/or control panel. If your hosting provider provides a guide then check it. The details (express, vite, etc) are irrelevant at this point. Your current goal is to bind mywebsite.com:443 to localhost:5000, as said

@EstusFlask Thank you so much for the guidance, it is really helpful! Do i NEED node.js? My server providor says it costs me like 5€ extra per month.

Good you mentioned it. Yes, you absolutely need it, because you run express with node.js. You need to run node server on server start. On low level this can be done with PM2, but if CP provides easier ways to do this then that's it. You're not supposed to pay extra if you really have vps because you can install whatever you need to it through ssh. If you really are then the provider isn't worth it imo. There are node-friendly providers like heroku that won't require low-level details, whether they are cost-efficient is another question

@EstusFlask honestly not sure what they are on about, I think they mostly do Wordpress and have limited knowledge on anything else. I tried install via ssh and it seems I got both npm and node running "[admin@server ~]$ node -v
v20.11.1"

This is what's expected for a vps, so it's ok. TLDR: You need to add static middleware to express to serve static files instead of public_html, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10434001 . You need pm2 to run node server on server restart, unless you want to do this manually, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/4018154 . "How to bind mysite.com:443 to localhost:5000 in directadmin" can give a couple of clues with gpt. If you want to use https (which is reasonable and presumed by 443), you need to additinally take care of  ssl certificates, this is what hosting support is supposed to help with

@EstusFlask thank you Estus! I will have to look more into the documentation it seems. I thought it would be easier since it was so easy to get it working on localhost. However it seems most tutorials are only localhost and very few actually deploy stuff to the real world. Since all this is new to me it seems very hard, but I will try :)

You're welcome. This is the responsibility of a web admin. This presumes that you as a web dev have one that handles this for you, since you rent a server. Otherwise you need to learn some new things along the way
